# If the UK Gov. has authority to cancel article 50 notification, why do they have to agree an extension with the EU

Tags: brexit

Unless I've misunderstood the news months gone by, the UK has always *requested* an extension which has then been voted on by the other EU member states.

However I've also read that the UK can, at any time, revoke article 50 - without requiring the agreement or cooperation of the EU, the ball is firmly in our court, the power of revelation is the UKs.

With the UK able to cancel and simply reissue the article 50  notification as it sees fit, it seems needless to agree extensions. It also seems unusual that there is a default timeline given altogether (why say 2 years from submitting another article 50 notification to leaving the EU, if the leaving state can do as I've suggested). I understand that this may be a politically bad move (essentially the leaving state annoying the EU) but as negotiations continue it seems like there is little love lost anyway.

Comment: *It also seems unusual that there is a default timeline given altogether (why say 2 years from submitting article 50 to leaving the EU, if the leaving state can do as I've suggested).* – This deadline might also be in the interest of the leaving member state, since otherwise the remaining members could block the exit by not agreeing to any withdrawal agreement. It didn’t turn out that way in the current UK situation, but it could have.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The ECJ [decided](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf;jsessionid=4319176A43A408772066916DB6123F2E?text=&docid=208636&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=10214917)

> Article 50 TEU must be interpreted as meaning that, where a Member State has notified the European Council, in accordance with that article, of its intention to withdraw from the European Union, that article allows that Member State — for as long as a withdrawal agreement concluded between that Member State and the European Union has not entered into force or, if no such agreement has been concluded, for as long as the two-year period laid down in Article 50(3) TEU, possibly extended in accordance with that paragraph, has not expired — to revoke that notification unilaterally, in an unequivocal and unconditional manner, by a notice addressed to the European Council in writing, after the Member State concerned has taken the revocation decision in accordance with its constitutional requirements. The purpose of that revocation is to confirm the EU membership of the Member State concerned under terms that are unchanged as regards its status as a Member State, and that revocation brings the withdrawal procedure to an end.

Two interesting points here:

- The revocation must be **unequivocal and unconditional** and
- it must be **in accordance with [its] constitutional requirements**.

Revoking to prolong the negotiating period would fail at least in the first regard, possibly in both points. The question is, would the EU27 call it out or would it let the trick pass?

(By the way, revoking Article 50 means nobody can leave the EU any more. What you mean is revoking the Article 50 *notification*.)

Comment: At best, the fist point is valid until the next general election. [No Parliament may bind another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_sovereignty)

Comment: @Jontia, a state may enter binding international treaties and would be expected to abide by them, whatever their *domestic* rules say.

Comment: The EU makes clear that its constituent nations remain sovereign and their internal processes are respected. Very little could be more damaging Internationally to the EU than to suggest that a fresh Parliament, with a new mandate based on a election manifesto could not re-invoke article 50. It may be frustrating, and the political relationship between the UK and the EU may be damaged, but I can't believe they would not allow article 50 to be resubmitted under those circumstances. They might with all haste look to modify article 50 to explicitly stop such shenanigans in the future.

Comment: @Jontia, I have no doubt the EU27 would let the UK leave. They may not offer a different Brexit treaty.

Comment: @o.m.: But, since, no Parliament may bind another, all the next Parliament has to do is repeal the ratification of the treaty.

Comment: @o.m.: At this point I wouldn't trust one Parliament's treaty with the E.U. to be of any value the moment the next Parliament sits.

Comment: @Sean, repealing a *Brexit* treaty would mean repealing *Brexit*. I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @o.m. nope, Brexit and any agreement about what happens after Brexit are two things very much intertwined but at the same time entirely separate.  Repealing the Withdrawal Agreement, if it ever was passed into legislation, would certainly leave a huge uncertain mess but the UK would still be out if the EU, the only things affected would be the UKs relationship and legal obligations with regard to the EU.

Comment: @Moo, that depends on what the Brexit agreements actually says. The draft proposal seems deal in the water, so we cannot know that.

Comment: @o.m. you really think any version of a withdrawal agreement would contain any version of "if this treaty or agreement is repealed or voided in any way, the UK reverts to being a member of the EU"?  Nope.  When out the UK is out, the agreements are about the relationships after the UK is out.

Comment: @Moo, UK media and politics talked about the convention on treaties as an end run around the backstop. This has gone quiet after the initial excitement. What you propose seems to be more of the same.

Comment: @o.m. I'm not proposing anything, I'm taking issue with your earlier comment that Brexit can be repealed by a future government - it cannot.  The treaties around it can, they are just domestic legislation, but repealing those treaties would not put the UK back into the EU, hence there is no way to "repeal" Brexit after the exit happens.  It's pretty simple really.

Comment: @o.m. EU membership is a treaty (or a set of treaties, but for simplicity let's call it a treaty). Once the UK is out of the EU, that treaty no longer governs the relationship between the UK and the EU. The withdrawal agreement is an agreement about the conditions for terminating the UK's participation in the EU treaty. Once that participation is ended, it can only be restored through the process in Article 49. Article 50 is explicit on that.  If the UK withdraws from the WA that will only affect post-Brexit obligations that arise from the WA.

Comment: @Jontia ‘and the political relationship between the UK and the EU may be damaged’ – how much more damaged than the current state of affairs can the political relationship become?

Answer (score 8):

[Article 50 of the Treaty of the European Union](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A12012M050) indicates that an extension of the notice period requires the consent of all other member states:

> 3. The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned, unanimously decides to extend this period.

However, Article 50 says nothing about the retraction of any withdrawal notice.  In that light, we go to the [Vienna Convention on the Law of Treaties](http://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/1_1_1969.pdf).  Article 68 of the Convention states that:

> A notification or instrument provided for in article 65 or 67 [invalidation, termination, withdrawal or suspension of a treaty] may be revoked at any time before it takes effect.

Of course, such a notification must be done in a manner that's consistent with the domestic law of the relevant country (UK law, in this case).

Comment: Why do you think the Vienna Convention is more relevant in this case than the ECJ ruling, which *also* gives a right to revoke?

Comment: The ECJ's ruling is based on the Vienna Convention.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the legal difficulties, cancelling and reissuing the article 50 notification will most likely amount to political suicide. Doing so is not a simple extension by a short while, it is an extension by two years as the process will start anew. Think about what will happen in this time:

- The EU will still insist on the terms similar to those negotiated before. The only way for the UK to put pressure on the EU was the threat of having a hard Brexit, which you now removed (not that it worked so far), so there is no real chance to get a better agreement in your name.
- While opinions differ whether Brexit will ultimately be good or bad for the economy, I think both sides will agree that the current uncertainty is not helpful. Think about what will happen if you extend the current chaos by another two years.
- There will definitely be a snap election. The only thing that has prevented this in the last months was the fear that doing so will take to long and Brexit will happen while there is no government. Whoever was responsible for reissuing article 50 has at this point angered the leave camp by postponing everything by another two years, angered the remain camp by insisting on still doing so and angered everyone in between by effectively bringing Brexit to a total of half a decade of bickering and chaos.
- Parliamentary elections won't be the only thing up for vote. Now that there is time, there will be new calls for a second referendum. Furthermore Scotland will try again for independence, this time with proper chances and Northern Ireland might similarly decide to solve the backstop problem once and for all by seceding and finally joining Ireland.

And there are probably a few other points I have missed. I am not saying that this will not happen, but even in the long sequence of stupid political moves that brought us to today, I would consider cancelling reissuing article 50 in the same move as a crowning achievement.

Comment: I think there have been no more snap elections because the Conservatives don't want to risk losing their majority to the Brexit party. Under Boris, they may go down that road.

Comment: Two more years of uncertainty is still a lot better than the worst forms of Brexit.

Comment: @Christopher Might be, but for this question it is actually irrelevant. From the start, the driving force for all people involved was never really "what's better for Britain", but "what's better for me (and maybe my party)". In the case of hard Brexit, you can deflect the blame toward someone else (pick one excuse according to political preference: EU didn't was unreasonable, parliament didn't accept the great deal, Brexit was stupid in the first place, etc.). In case you were the one extending the chaos for two more years, the whole blame is on you.

Comment: @Christopher actually, there's no guarantee that it would be two years.  Under the terms of Art. 50, the exit date is "the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement," with a 2-year deadline if no agreement can be reached.  (The deadline can also be extended with unanimous consent.)  A country can invoke article 50 and then leave as soon as it can reach an agreement with the European Council.  Theoretically, that could be the next day.  The problem here is that such a course of action would generate a good deal of ill will and uncertainty.

Answer (score -5):

The EU wants to make it easy for members to stay, and hard for members to leave. If a member decides that the process to leave is too difficult, they are allowed to change their mind and stay under the same conditions as before.

The EU doesn't want a member to crash out without an agreement that is good for the EU. (The agreement might be good for the leaving member too, but that's the member's responsibility, not the EU's.) Imagine if the EU made it hard to leave AND hard to stay! What would a member do in that case? It would probably crash out without a beneficial agreement, and the EU doesn't want that.

Comment: I do wonder about your assertion there. Obviously any agreement that any party will agree to will have advantages for that party. Looking at the no-deal scenario, it should be rather clear than as good as any agreement has benefits for both sides *a priori*. I would think if Ireland (the island) and the border there didn’t exist, we wouldn’t be having all this discussion, the UK would have been thrown out in March – but because no Irish border also means no backstop we might well have a parliament-accepted deal and the UK having left in March.

Comment: @Jan I just watched a really good video about this. It's all about **agreement**. If the UK wants to cancel the Article 50 process, at the momemt the EU will agree and doesn't need to be asked. However, the date for leaving was agreed first at the start of the Article 50 process (2 years), then by extensions.